# gunzip multiple compressed files to another directory without deleting the .gz files

Tags: shell, gzip

I have multiple `.gz` file in a folder and I want to unzip it in other folder through `gunzip` without deleting parent file. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean something like `gunzip -c folder1/myfile.gz > folder2/myfile`?
With the `-c` option, `gunzip` keeps the original files unchanged.

If you want to do it for all `.gz` files in `folder1`, you could use

```
cd folder1; for f in *.gz ; do gunzip -c "$f" > ../folder2/"${f%.*}" ; done
```

Comment: Hi Anthon,

I am trying to do the same thing 
what I did from unzip method: 

" unzip folder1/'*.gz' -d folder2 "

I want to do the same thing through gunzip.

Comment: gunzip does not have an option that is equivalent to unzip's `-d`. You have to write the loop yourself. Alternatively, copy all .gz files to the target directory and uncompress them there using `gunzip *.gz`.

Comment: I tried above command and I got " folder2/file: No such file or directory " error

Comment: Does `folder2` exist already? Otherwise you have to create it using `mkdir` before you start the loop.

Comment: Its working now, Thanks Uwe for your help. I was trying to create **folder2** outside of **folder1** while unzipping the file.